# NodeJS - calling functions and structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, discord

I'm pretty new to Javascript and NodeJs, I was just wondering how I would structure this so it would produce a message in the following structure: title and caption. So what I'm trying to do is initialize the variables, then wrote up a function to scrap data from a website (`scrapData`), then that function would be ran then put the information into the arrays (`titles, captions, images_long`), then the loop will produce the messages with the `title and caption`. I'm just confused on the structure and calling functions. Here is the code for the command:

```
if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + 'latest')) {

        //website url variables
        var website_domain = "websitedomain.com/";
        var website_path = args;
        var website_url = website_domain + website_path;

        //array for elements scrapped
        var titles = [];
        var captions = [];
        var images_long = [];

        //opening url and scrapping elements
        function scrapData(website_url) {
            request(website_url, function(err, resp, body) {
                var $ = cheerio.load(body);

                //retrieves titles
                $('.title').each(function() {
                    var title = $(this).children('h2').children('span').text();
                    titles.push(title);
                });

                //retrieves captions
                $('.post-box-excerpt').each(function() {
                    var caption = $(this).children('p').text();
                    captions.push(caption);
                });

                //retrieves images
                $('.thumbnail').each(function() {
                    var image = $(this).children('img').attr('src');
                    images_long.push(image);
                });

            });
        }

        scrapData(website_url);

        //produce embed messages
        for (i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {

            const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                .setColor('#8E44AD')
                .addField(((i + 1) + ". " + titles[i]), captions[i], true);
                //set images here

            message.channel.send({embed});

        }

    }
```

Comment: Not sure what you are asking but I would change the code a bit. If any block you are scraping is missing .post-box-excerpt og .thumbnail all next will be pushed to wrong index.

Find the parent block (div) of .title, .post-box-excerpt, .thumbnail and take a .each loop of that and do rest of your .each loop for title, caption and thumbnail inside this loop.

Comment: functions are asynchronous and your expectations are to be executed synchronous. You need to chain the functions or re-write the login to execute one-by-one

Comment: @Lostfields sorry, so what this command is trying to do is collect website from a website that the user wants, for example they would type in: h.latest footwear and it would produce a message for the latest articles (this example, footwear) on the site into discord (a text + voice chat app). Basically I want to make it so user types in command with desired category -> combine the category argument + domain variable to create the url -> run the scrapping function to add the title, caption and images to the lists -> loop will produce message with title and caption field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your call to scrapData have to wait for the request (that is async) to be done before it can handle the data. You have to put all your code into the callback of your original request, or consider using promises (Promises will support the nice async/await in NodeJS 7+)

Change your require("request") to require("request-promise-native") instead and do something like this:

```
function scrapData(website_url) {
    return request(website_url)
        .then(body => {
            let items = [],
                $ = cheerio.load(body);

            $('.post-box').each((index, element) => {
                let title = $(element).find('.title h2 span').first().text(),
                    caption = $(element).find('.post-box-excerpt p').first().text(),
                    thumbnail = $(element).find('.thumbnail img').first().attr('src');

                items.push({ title, caption, thumbnail })
            })
            return items;
        })
}

scrapData(website_url)
    .then(items => {
        //produce embed messages
        for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
        {

            const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                .setColor('#8E44AD')
                .addField(((i + 1) + ". " + items[i].title), items[i].caption, true);
            //set images here

            message.channel.send({ embed });
        }
    })
```

I didn't like the way you scraped title, caption and thumbnail since the indexed could come unsynced. Let say you are missing one caption for the second index, then you will have titles of ['title 1', 'title 2', 'title 3'] and caption like: ['caption 1', 'caption 3']. Make sure you scrape the title and caption of a parent block. Not sure how you use cheerio but I tried to do my best in the example.

NB, one important thing, `$('').each(function() { $(this) })` is not the same as `$('').each(() => { $(this) })` since this is in different scopes. Google scope and arrow function. You may change my arrow functions to normal functions or solve this by using the arguments of each like `$('').each( (index, element) => { $(element) })`

Comment: So for the '$('.parentblock_of_title&post-box-excerpt&thumbnail')', it would be  $('.post-box') - here is the website https://hypebeast.com/adidas I'm trying to scrap from. I also noticed that scrapping your way only takes the first article from the site and produces 10 of the same messages.

Comment: How would I make it retrieve 10 different articles instead of the 10 same ones?

Comment: @hsel updated the example with correct selectors. it worked for me at least.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [Crawler Package Nodejs](https://github.com/bda-research/node-crawler).

It work very well for me.

And use [Async](https://github.com/caolan/async) for working with asynchronous JavaScript